# Grails: Rendering two Views simultaneously with one Controller Action

Tags: grails, view, controller

One action of one of my controllers needs to generate(redirect/render) two separate views simultaneously and show both the pages to the client. It will be like when the user submits his info, the page will redirect to a new page with a list. **At the same time** another page needs to **pop up in a new window** containing some additional info (user would print this page). I know, I can resolve the issue with a single page, but I was wondering whether there is any ways to produce two separate pages/windows simultaneously from a single controller action.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use a `<script>window.open()</script>` in your main view in order to open the popup?

Comment: Mercy boucoup. I used your solution and blended with @peddn

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is NO. Grails isn't doing anything magical.  It's still constrained to normal HTTP request/response lifecycle.  A single request gets a single response.  What you're asking for sounds like you want grails to be able to generate 2 responses for a single HTTP request which is impossible.  The response is either a page for the browser to render or it's a redirect message for the browser to go to another URL.

Comment: Gratitude for the insight. Didn't think this way. You are absolutely right though this does not give me the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could write your action that it can handle normal and ajax requests. See the docs here:
[Responding to both Ajax and non-Ajax requests](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#ajaxOnTheServer)

Then you could generate your "normal" view. After that you call the same action by using ajax on the client side and load the data for your pop up page.

Comment: Of course this is only a "workaround" for the problem Tri mentined... But perhaps it's a solution you can live with.